# Trouble aligning LI element

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting my LI elements to align closer to the left side of their container.  I have my HTML below, and when it displays the LI elements have a margin on the left of about 30 pixels.  I would like to see how I could make that flush against their container, and then once I understand that technique, I can adjust it so there is some left padding.

Btw, I did create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/SXajC/1/) with this to make it easier to see the problem, but unfortunately jsFiddle shows the result I want to see!  If the below HTML is copied/pasted to a file and brought up in Chrome, it looks different (each LI is shifted to the right).

Here is the HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .parentSelectorBox
        {
        }
        .parentSelectorBox .fieldsBox
        {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 250px;
            margin: 5px;
            float: left;
        }
        .parentSelectorBox .actionButtonsBox
        {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 5px;
            float: left;
        }
        .parentSelectorBox .availableFields
        {
            border: 1px solid pink;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .parentSelectorBox ul li
        {
            height: 20px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0 10 0 -15px;
            padding: 0 10 0 -15px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            marker-offset: 105px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parentSelectorBox" class="parentSelectorBox">
        <div id="availableFieldsBox" class="fieldsBox">
            <div id="availableFields" class="availableFields">
                <ul>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>A</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If jsFiddle show the result fine, then it's probably something else in your code I guess...

Comment: Set `margin` and `padding` to `0` for the `li` and all its ancestor elements. Also, you can't have negative padding. @elclanrs: JS Fiddle uses a reset stylesheet to remove default styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `padding` property of the `ul`:

```
.parentSelectorBox ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the padding from the ul-element.

```
ul{padding:0px;}
```

Should work. Removing the margin is not necessary for your problem!

PS: Uncheck the "Normalized CSS"-checkbox on the left side of the fiddle to see your problem.

Comment: Actually, removing the margin from the `ul` is necessary. The OP indicated that the version shown in the fiddle is what he's looking for. Without removing the margin from the `ul`, there will be a margin at the top...

Comment: Okay, if he wants exactly the result from the fiddle, he has to remove the margin.
But he only wanted to get his "LI elements to align closer to the left side of their container", so it isn't really necessary.

Comment: From his post: "but unfortunately jsFiddle shows the result I want to see!"